# Scala Reflection: Invoking a Function1's apply method - multiple alternatives?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I'm trying to invoke a function using the scala reflection api in v2.11.6:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

def f(i: Int) = i + 2

val fn: Any = (f _)
val ref = ru.runtimeMirror(ru.getClass.getClassLoader).reflect(fn)
val apply = ref.symbol.typeSignature.member(ru.TermName("apply"))
```

When using `ref.reflectMethod(apply.asMethod)` it complains about multiple alternatives to `apply` on `ref`. Examining `apply.asTerm.alternatives` reveals two methods, one with signature `(x$1: Int)Int` and the other with `(v1: T1)R`. Calling

```
ref.reflectMethod(apply.asTerm.alternatives(1).asInstanceOf[ru.MethodSymbol])(1)
```

(with the second alternative) returns the correct result (3). However calling the first alternative raises an exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class`

What are those alternatives and how can I make sure to always invoke the proper one? There also seems to be a problem with invoking a Function2 or higher with this method, so what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why there are overloaded `apply` methods is that `Function1` is `@specialized` for primitive types.

I don't know if there is a better way to distinguish them, but the following seems to work, looking for the alternative whose argument erases to `AnyRef` (instead of a primitive such as `Int`):

```
def invoke(fun1: Any, arg1: Any): Any = {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
  val mirror  = ru.runtimeMirror(ru.getClass.getClassLoader)
  val ref     = mirror.reflect(fn)
  val applies = ref.symbol.typeSignature.member(ru.TermName("apply"))
  val syms    = apply.alternatives.map(_.asMethod)  
  val sym     = syms.find { m =>
    m.paramLists match {
      case (arg :: Nil) :: Nil 
        if arg.asTerm.typeSignature.erasure =:= ru.typeOf[AnyRef] => true
      case _ => false
    }
  } getOrElse sys.error("No generic apply method found")
  ref.reflectMethod(sym)(arg1)
}

// Test:
val fn: Any = (i: Int) => i + 2
invoke(fn, 1)  // res: 3
```

Comment: @Pyetras - great, didn't know that existed.